# Call OnClick handler after window.close()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have ASP.NET WebForms app, and the is browser popup window with button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAllocate" runat="server" Text="Allocate" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnAllocate_Click" 
OnClientClick="window.close(); __doPostBack('btnAllocate','')" />
```

So, I need execute my server-side handler `btnAllocate_Click` after window closed. But it isn't fired. What's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if the window closing is preventing the postBack from running since the context the javascript is in will be gone.  Why can't you call `__doPostBack` first, and then close?

Answer (score 0):

Erik might be right. I will do postback in the window.onunload event of the page that the popup opens. Something like this:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onunload = function () {
      __doPostBack('btnAllocate', '');
   }
</script>
...
<asp:Button ID="btnAllocate" runat="server" Text="Allocate" CssClass="button" 
 OnClientClick="window.close();" onclick="btnAllocate_Click" />
...
```